# How to send MultiPart and RequestBody together In Spring-boot 2.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I'm implementing microservices in Spring-boot. I try to send **@RequestBody** with a **MultipartFile** together. I refereed some questions in stackoverflow, but nothing helps me.

**Video class**

```
@Data
public class Video{

    @id
    ObjectId _id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    List<String> tags;
}
```

Method

```
@PostMapping(RequestUrl.VIDEO_ADD_VIDEO)
public ResponseEntity<BulkWriteResult> addNewVideoToCategory(
    @RequestBody Video video
    @RequestPart MultipartFile file) {
    // some logics

}
```

In application.properties

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true 
spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize=1000000KB
spring.servlet.multipart.maxRequestSize=1000000KB
```

The error Im getting is,

```
  "timestamp": "2020-04-21T12:15:37.592+00:00",
  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "message": "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarydksa0TRBbc8VmBzU;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
  "trace": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarydksa0TRBbc8VmBzU;charset=UTF-8' not supported\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:225)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:158)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:131)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)\r\n",
  "path": "/video/add-video"
}
```

But I wonder, the multipart file (`@RequestPart`) is working with `@RequestParam` if I send all fields as params.

After referring some questions, I added

```
@Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {        
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }
```

But no luck. I tried to send the **Video Object** as Request Part also, since no luck. Thanks in advance.

***Update 1.***

Just tried to use both as **@RequestPart** and attached how I requested as screenshot

```
@PostMapping(RequestUrl.VIDEO_ADD_VIDEO)
public ResponseEntity<BulkWriteResult> addNewVideoToCategory(
    @RequestPart("body") Video video
    @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {      

}
```

[image: Postman]

**Default headers**
[image: Header]

Error is `Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define body as `RequestPart` too.

```java
@PostMapping(RequestUrl.VIDEO_ADD_VIDEO)
public ResponseEntity<BulkWriteResult> addNewVideoToCategory(
    @RequestPart("body") Video video
    @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
    // some logics

}
```

Comment: it shows error `Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported`

Comment: which client do you use ?

Comment: could you add the postman printscreen on the question please ?

Comment: Ok it misses the content type tab in postman. For "body" part set to `application/json. For "file" part nothing to change

Comment: Please let me know how to set it up

Comment: you have 3 tabs : key , value and description -> click on 3 bullet and check content-type. For row defining the body part set content-type column with `application/json` ... more clear now ?

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried to use RequestPart in body part but I still have an issue. How can I fix it? Can you help me? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903123/cannot-send-requestbody-and-multipartfile-in-controller-of-spring-boot-from-post