# Cannot send requestbody and Multipartfile in Controller of Spring Boot from Postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, multipartfile

I have a problem to send requestBody and multipartFile in Controller of Spring Boot from Postman.

I get this issue shown below as an image

[image]

Here is the method of controller shown below

```
@PostMapping(produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> createQrCode(@RequestBody CreateQrRequest request, @RequestPart MultipartFile imageFile) throws IOException {

}
```

Here is **CreateQrRequest** shown below

```
@Data
@Builder
public class CreateQrRequest {

    @NotBlank
    private String text;

    @NotBlank
    private String size;

    @NotBlank
    private String color;

    @NotBlank
    private String backgroundColor;
}
```

Here is the error message when I tried to define the parameters like

```
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> createQrCode(@RequestPart CreateQrRequest request, 
                                               @RequestPart MultipartFile imageFile) throws IOException {
```

Error Message

```
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "detail": "Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported.",
    "instance": "/api/v1/qr-generator"
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Best lookup enabling octet-stream in the server config for requests and post.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant How can I enabling octet-stream?

Comment: What server are you using?   Here is some of that type of way.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75687109/how-can-i-limit-the-body-of-a-application-octet-stream-request-in-spring-boot

Comment: @SamuelMarchant Tomcat. I think there is a problem in createQrCode method.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant When I use this option `public ResponseEntity<byte[]> createQrCode(@RequestPart String text, @RequestPart String size, @RequestPart String color, @RequestPart String backgroundColor, @RequestPart MultipartFile imageFile) throws IOException`  , it works. However, I want to send a RequestBody

Comment: From both errors it is definitely a server config issue, a QR code however may be a mime type "image/png"   or "image/jpg" what does it generate?  Too if you are sending in a request from a multiparty form, all you need to do is put "the data" piece through the url encoder first to make it a pseudo string. Post or Get email form "data" is url encoder first!  A better way of comprehending it is after all pieces are url encoder first and then joined together finally, it then has a Content-Length

Comment: You then are using multiparty/form-data form type , but is the QR code image an attachment or in the body? If in the body part then it is best type text/html and in an html IMG element to use a base64 image data coding in the SRC=

Comment: @SamuelMarchant I don't think there is a server issue. The problem is related with this part `(@RequestPart CreateQrRequest request, 
                                               @RequestPart MultipartFile imageFile) `

Comment: When using application/octet-stream the content-transfer-encoding would be "binary". However I presume much of this is done by the system.   The answer by someone below seems credible from this tutorial.   https://www.baeldung.com/java-generating-barcodes-qr-codes

Comment: @SamuelMarchant I use ZXing library in my example. My issue is related with the request part with variables. `@RequestPart` didn't help me fix the issue.

Comment: Not finding good api info for it , this following is in some way a Result not a requestpart @RequestPart MultipartFile.     Too, is the byte[] array returned only image data or a whole message?   Is that emailed or sent straight out http "Are you writing your own annotations for this code?". E.g. Qrproductioninput     Qrproductioninputparam    Qrproductionoutput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the controller like below -

```java
 @PostMapping(produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> createQrCode(@RequestPart String text, @RequestPart String size, @RequestPart String color, @RequestPart String backgroundColor, @RequestPart MultipartFile imageFile) throws IOException {

    }
```

Just writing the request's attributes separately.

Comment: Is it impossible to use CreateQrRequest request?

Comment: Not sure, once I faced this issue, and solved it this way. If you find anything, please post the solution here.

Comment: I have a problem about the custom validation in this example. Can you help me if you have any idea. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75918125/how-to-use-custom-validation-with-requestparam-in-spring-boot