# How to use Custom validation with @RequestParam in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I have a problem to detect custom validation in Spring Boot example. I defined some validation including in color validator, text length validator and image size validator.

When I try to send a request with non validation values, it passed successfully instead of throwing an error.

How can I fix it? I also shared my repo shown below

Here is the Controller  shown below

```
@Validated
    public class QrController {
    
        @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<byte[]> createQrCode(@RequestParam String text,
                                                   @RequestParam String size,
                                                   @RequestParam String color,
                                                   @RequestParam String backgroundColor,
                                                   @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile imageFile) throws IOException {
        
                CreateQrRequest request = CreateQrRequest.builder()
                        .text(text)
                        .backgroundColor(backgroundColor)
                        .color(color)
                        .size(size)
                        .build();
        
                ....
        
        }
    }
```

Here is the CreateQrRequest shown below

```
@Data
@Builder
public class CreateQrRequest {

    @NotBlank
    @TextLength
    private String text;

    @NotBlank
    @ImageSize
    private String size;

    @NotBlank
    @Color
    private String color;

    @NotBlank
    @Color
    private String backgroundColor;
}
```

Here is the Color annotation shown below

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ColorValidator.class)
@Target(value = {ElementType.FIELD , ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Color {
    String message() default "Invalid color hex code";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

Here is the ColorValidator shown below

```
public class ColorValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Color, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(Color constraintAnnotation) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String color, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

        return ValidatorUtil.validColor(color);
    }
}
```

**Edited**

I also added `ElementType.PARAMETER` to each validation annotation like `@Color`, `@TextLength` and `@ImageSize`.

Next I revised the method of controller shown below

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> createQrCode(@RequestParam @TextLength String text,
                                               @RequestParam @ImageSize String size,
                                               @RequestParam @Color String color,
                                               @RequestParam @Color String backgroundColor,
                                               @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile imageFile) throws IOException {
```

I got this issue shown below

```
jakarta.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'com.example.qrgeneratorexample.utils.annotation.TextLength' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'createQrCode.text'
```

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/qr-generator-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to fix it by using all these steps shown below

1 ) Add Constraint annotation to method of controller

```
 @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> createQrCode(@RequestParam @TextLengthConstraint @NotBlank String text,
                                               @RequestParam @ImageSizeConstraint @NotBlank String size,
                                               @RequestParam @ColorConstraint @NotBlank String color,
                                               @RequestParam @ColorConstraint @NotBlank String backgroundColor,
                                               @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile imageFile) throws IOException {
```

2 ) Define constraint like this shown below

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ColorValidator.class)
@Target(value = {ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ColorConstraint {
    String message() default "Invalid color hex code";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

3 ) Add `@Component` to validator

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ColorValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ColorConstraint, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ColorConstraint constraintAnnotation) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String color, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        log.info("ColorValidator | isValid is working");
        return ValidatorUtil.validColor(color);
    }
}
```